# No Access to external https source despite CORS is enabled for al in vite.config

Tags: vite, httpserver

If have the following configuration for vite:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import * as fs from 'fs';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {

    }, 
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
      preflightContinue: true
    },
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./.cert/key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./.cert/cert.pem'),
    }
  },
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  },
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

Also tried this with ...cors:true...
From my react code i try to acces the following json api
https://gegevensmagazijn.tweedekamer.nl/OData/v4/2.0/persoon

This always result in a CORS error
I can access this api from my pc directly with chrome and with postman.

I call it with this piece of javascript as a test:

```
 const response = await fetch("https://gegevensmagazijn.tweedekamer.nl/OData/v4/2.0/persoon");
 const person = await response.json();
 console.log(person);
```

Does anyone know how to configure the server and the fetch or axios call to accept CORS?

Comment: There are mutliple possible errors with cors. What is the exact error you get? Look in the developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you can't directly go to this api from javascript.
I created a small API parser in C#. which passes the OData from the source.
This works.